# Can't retag a certain question without editing its content

Tags: bug, editing, tags

I tried to suggest an edit to the tags on [this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/283/112), by removing the one tag it had, and adding two others I felt were more appropriate. I didn't find anything to change in the content.

However, when I clicked "Save Edits" I got the following message:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

and the edit was not submitted. I tried starting over from scratch and got the same result.

I believe that on other sites I've been allowed to do edits that simply changed the tags. [This meta question indicates that it's a normal thing to do.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215965/276524) Isn't it supposed to be the same, here?

I was able to get around it by making changes to the markup that don't change the way the content appears. Why wouldn't it work otherwise?

Comment: That's odd, I made tag change suggestion without a problem, see [here](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/315/revisions). Are you sure that you kept the body of the post unmodified?

Comment: @E_net4 I'm sure. I tried starting from the beginning another time with the same result.

Comment: Did you write an explanation, like "added tags"?

Comment: @Earthliŋ yes. The error message I received was specifically for the content, and different from the one when leaving the explanation out.

Answer (score -2):

Edits without the 6 character limit are only possible for users with the "[edit privilege](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)", currently >500 reputation (and in later stages of beta >1000 reputation, I think).

Sometimes it's a strange hurdle, but I think the idea is that any edit from a low-rep user has to be reviewed by two reviewers. So if two reviewers spend time looking at your edit, the system would like your edit to be worth at least 6 characters... (And for your effort you get +2 reputation, which you won't get once you can edit freely.)

Comment: The edit privilege is for making an immediate edit, without it going into the suggested edit queue. I've seen many suggested edits where the only change was tags on StackOverflow, for example. Also, [this edit from E_net4](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/315/revisions) appears to be another example of a suggested edit that changed zero characters of content.

Comment: I made a similar edit to the one Dan mentioned (tag only, with an explanation entered): http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/213/revisions

Comment: This answer was written in concept before, but removed some time later for having false conclusions. The OP is trying to **suggest** a tag edit.